# What is the recommended way to upload teenage volunteer and their parents data from csv file

Tags: data-import, upload

What is the recommended way to upload teenage volunteer and their parents data from csv file
This is the info looking to upload
First   Last    Email   Cell    Address City    State   Zip Home Phone  Email 2 Birthday    School  Gender
Moms Prefix Moms First Name Moms Last Name  Moms Cell   Moms Email  Moms Gender Moms Birthday
Father Prefix   Fathers Name    Fathers Last Name   Fathers Email   Fathers Gender  Fathers Birthday
Also...how do i group only the volunteer as group Volunteer & not the parents? Would you recommend to have the parents as a smart group such as parents of teenage volunteers for mailing purposes for example or to make a group called parents of teenage volunteers? How would i load that as part of this upload.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use relationships to tie the parent(s) to the teen.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/relationships/

Here is some information on importing relational data on this page. Just scroll down about 3/4 of the way down:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/